# Concatenat very third List items into one item

Tags: python-3.x

Hi am trying to concatenate every third item into one item:
I have :

```
dic = ['3', '3', '⛂', '3', '4', '⛀', '4', '3', '⛀', '4', '4', '⛂']
```

what i would like is to find a way to create a list of list with every third item

like

```
    dic = [['3', '3', '⛂'], ['3', '4', '⛀'], ['4', '3', '⛀'], ['4', '4', '⛂']]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go!

```
dic = ['3', '3', '⛂', '3', '4', '⛀', '4', '3', '⛀', '4', '4', '⛂']
lst=[]

for i in range(0,len(dic),3):
    lst.append(dic[i:i+3])
print(lst)
```

Output:

`[['3', '3', '⛂'], ['3', '4', '⛀'], ['4', '3', '⛀'], ['4', '4', '⛂']]`